# Unable to run dnf update, after adding packages-microsoft-com-prod

Tags: centos, powershell, repository, dnf

### Problem

I tried to install power shell core on a CentOS 8 sever. It didnt work so I tried a couple solutions from the web. It seems like I have added a repository twice. On dnf update I get this output:

```
[codingsafari@centosbox ~]$ sudo dnf update
[sudo] password for codingsafari:
Repository packages-microsoft-com-prod is listed more than once in the configuration
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                 90 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                     110 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                    43 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                       34 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00
packages-microsoft-com-prod                                                          22 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00
Killed
```

It did this killed at the end before as well but that was one step earlier at `extra packages...`

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

---

### Ways I have added the repo

first try didnt succeed and ended with killed

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft.repo
exit
sudo yum install -y powershell
```

This one I cannot really remember, I found these lines in the history though.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > ./microsoft-prod.repo
sudo cp ./microsoft-prod.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc > ./microsoft.asc
sudo rpm --import ./microsoft.asc
```

Thise was another thing I did

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft.repo
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum clean all
sudo dnf update
```

---

### Output of *ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d*

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  733 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-AppStream.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  714 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  800 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-centosplus.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1043 Jan  2 15:21 CentOS-CR.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  668 Jan  2 15:21 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  758 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-Extras.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  339 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  738 Jan  2 15:21 CentOS-HA.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  928 Jan  2 15:21 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  738 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-PowerTools.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1383 Sep 25 14:52 CentOS-Sources.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   74 Jan  2 15:21 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1351 Aug  6  2019 epel-playground.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1206 Aug  6  2019 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1305 Aug  6  2019 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  193 Feb 13 13:07 microsoft-prod.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  193 Feb 13 13:02 microsoft.repo
```

Comment: How did you add the repo? Can you post the contents of `ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d`? I am guessing you have two sources for packages-microsoft-com-prod.

Comment: @Bert thanks for the hint, I have updated my post. Now I see both ms repos, I guess I should just remove one of them. Any idea which one based on my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two files for that repo, remove either of them (as they are the same file), then run `yum update` to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Bert, thanks for the answer. I removed one of the repos and now it ends like that
`Out of memory allocating 771751936 bytes! Killed`

Comment: Its a linode/ nanode with  1 GB ram.  Its not that much but should this really happen? I guess no one could knew this and the problem is not solvable based on the question. You helped me to remove the dupe repo though, so I will accept your answer and open another question regarding this memory issue.

Comment: follow up question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1002971/linode-nanode-out-of-memory-allocating-when-running-yum-update